# Pandas DataFrame from DateTimeIndex to minutes or hours incremental counter

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to convert my DataFrame's indexes from DateTimeIndex (e.g., 2015-06-11 23:59:29) to an incremental hours counter like: [0h 1m, 0h 2m, 0h 3m, 0h 4m]. Is it possible?

Comment: Is the format, e.g. `0h 1m`, important? or would `HH:MM:SS` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a `HH:MM:SS` format is acceptable, you could change the DatetimeIndex into a TimedeltaIndex:

```
start = df.index.min()
df.index = df.index-start
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2015)
N = 10
index = pd.date_range('2015-7-24', periods=N, freq='15T')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(N,4)), index=index)
start = df.index.min()
df.index = df.index-start
print(df)
```

yields

```
          0  1  2  3
00:00:00  2  2  9  6
00:15:00  8  5  7  8
00:30:00  0  6  7  8
00:45:00  3  8  6  9
01:00:00  2  3  1  2
01:15:00  6  2  9  8
01:30:00  5  8  4  8
01:45:00  9  1  2  2
02:00:00  1  2  3  3
02:15:00  3  9  3  1
```

---

To plot the xtick labels in `0h 0m` format,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

np.random.seed(2015)
N = 10
index = pd.date_range('2015-7-24', periods=N, freq='15T')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(N,4)).astype(float), index=index)
start = df.index.min()
df.index = df.index-start
df.index /= np.timedelta64(1, 'm')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(kind='line', ax=ax)
def xfmt(x, pos):
    hours, minutes = divmod(x, 60)
    return '{:g}h {:02g}m'.format(hours, minutes)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(xfmt))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: great! question: df.plot() prints '0 days 02:19:58'... how can I avoid to print the '0 days' part?

Comment: and how can I plot as xticks just the number of minutes?

Comment: solution: ```df.index / np.timedelta64(1,'m')``` found the solution here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion

Comment: @EnricoRotundo: Yes, that's a good way to find to total number of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

[HappyLeadSecond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/happyleapsecond)'s solution works just for start the indexing from the first row.

According to the [api](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion), in order to convert such indexes to minutes or whatever just do:

`df.index / np.timedelta64(1,'m')`